# SwiftyJson Swift 3 cannot access string in JSON

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, native, swifty-json

I'm having trouble accessing "token" using SwiftyJson. loginTokens is a global variable that has some JSON data stored inside. See below print.

My code never runs to print(token).

As described in these docs, it should be working...
https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
        print(loginTokens)
        if let token = loginTokens["token"].string{
            print(token)
        }
    }
```

print(loginTokens) outputs:

```
{
    "customer" : {
        "href" : "myURL.com"
    },
    "token" : "kkasd012030-asdasd9kk"
}
```

loginTokens is set like this:

App Delegate:

```
if let tokens = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "loginTokens"){
    loginTokens = JSON(tokens)
}
```

Comment: What is the type of the loginTokens?

Comment: try .rawString()

Comment: @V.Khambir it is type JSON. Please see my edit

Comment: @ThomasCharlesworth And how you store data of loginTokens in UserDefaults?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `tokens` has to be of type `Data`.

Use the following to convert `tokens` to `Data` before

```
loginTokens = JSON(data: tokens.data(using: .utf8))
```